# Download file with curl and pipe it through sha1sum into tar

Tags: bash, curl, pipe, checksum

I would like to download a file with curl, check its checksum with sha1sum (or a similar tool) and pipe the file into tar to unpack it, given that the result of sha1sum was a 0.

I know that without the checksum verfication it would be a simple `curl <link> | tar x` , however I'm having a hard time fitting sha1sum in there since its syntax is very foreign to me. I could probably manage to do it if sha1sum was able to receive the checksum as a parameter and read the file from stdin, but as far as I have seen this is not possible. Is there a way to achieve this nontheless?

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do this directly. `sha1sum` (and the various other `*sum` tools aren't designed to be pipelined like that. They don't send the file to standard output to let you continue the pipeline. You could duplicate the stream to *both* `sha1sum` and `tar` (and kill `tar` if/when `sha1sum` fails) but that might be the best you can do).

Answer (score 0):

```
set -ex; \
curl -o wordpress.tar.gz -fSL "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-4.7.3.tar.gz"; \
echo "35adcd8162eae00d5bc37f35344fdc06b22ffc98 *wordpress.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c -; \
tar -xzf wordpress.tar.gz -C ./
```